# how to add new inserted row to tableview with out reloading total tableview?

Tags: iphone

hi to all i am new to iphone,please help to me in my application i displayed all messages access from database through webservices(with user image,message image and message)and provide message posting option to post new message and store in database i can display all messages on tableview and post message correctly but my problem is when post new message(with image)it correctly stored in database how can i add new record to tableview with out reload total tableview because reload table takes large time to access from database.

Comment: By the way, to be a good participant here, you need to Accept good answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `insertRowAtIndexPaths:`.

```
NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];

[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[tableView endUpdates];
```